# select from table where both id exist

Tags: sql

I need to select from a single table where both id exists in the column having matching id in another column.
My query is like below which gives rows with even just single matching id.

```
select * from customer_appdata where appdata_id in(11,12) 

id  customer_id appdata_id  
6    65             4
7    65             12  
8    65             8   
9    66             11  
10   66             12
```

so here i just want last and second last rows(9,10) as they have both 11 and 12 with common id 66.

Comment: What does 11,12 have to do with 9,10 or 66?  Confused.  Please clarify your question.  It is not clear.  Please specify db platform.

Comment: Can you have multiple records with the same `customer_id` and the same `appdata_id`?

Comment: `select * from customer_appdata where appdata_id in(11,12) AND customer_id = 66` no? Your question is really not clear.

Comment: Do you want to find only customers that have only those appdata_ids, or customers that have them both (but can have additional ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query selects rows with customer_appdata of 12 or 11 and uses `exists` to see if the other row is also in the table.

```
select * from customer_appdata c1
where appdata_id in (11,12)
and exists (
    select 1 from customer_appdata c2
    where c2.appdata_id in (11,12)
    and c2.appdata_id <> c1.appdata_id
    and c2.customer_id = c1.customer_id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, this should work:

```
select * from customer_appdata where customer_id in (
  select customer_id from customer_appdata
  where appdata_id in (11,12) 
  group by customer_id
  having count(distinct appdata_id) = 2
)
```

You find all customer_ids that are repeated specific number of times (that's the inner query) and then select all rows with those customer_ids. There is probably a faster way, but if performance is not critical this is a simple way to solve the problem.

Comment: I edited the answer, because I just now realized the real problem you want to solve. The first version would be doing something different than you expect.

Comment: you need to change having count(distinct appdata_id) = 2 to  having count(appdata_id) > 2. appdata_id can be more than 2

Comment: distinct appdata_id can't be more than two, because I'm filtering them on only two values. This is needed to make sure I have matched both 11 and 12 in the group.