# SELECT WHERE multiple records don't exist

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables.

**attempts:**

```
id
40
41
42
43
```

**attempt_tags:**

```
id    attemptid    tagid
1     40           2
2     42           4
3     40           11
4     43           10
5     44           2
```

I'm looking to select a record from the `attempts` table where (for example) `tagid` 2 and 11 are **BOTH** not present, so the result of the query in this example would return everything except for id 40.

I initially thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812365/select-from-table-where-both-id-exist) would be a good solution, but I'm not as convinced now, I imagine in the scenario where I need to select the results that don't have many `tagid`'s present (e.g. 2, 11, 15, 18, 20, 25 etc), this query would end up getting quite long.

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I'm just not seeing it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`, twice:

```
select a.*
from attempts a
where not exists (select 1
                  from attempt_tags att
                  where att.attemptid = a.id and
                        att.tagid = 2
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from attempt_tags att
                  where att.attemptid = a.id and
                        att.tagid = 11
                 ) ;
```

EDIT:

You can also simplify this to:

```
select a.*
from attempts a
where not exists (select 1
                  from attempt_tags att
                  where att.attemptid = a.id and
                        att.tagid in (2, 11)
                 ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you - I think this would work, but surely there has to be a simpler way - there's the potential for I think around 20 different tagid's, so generating a query that has that many iterations of NOT EXISTS doesn't seem like the best solution

Comment: @MarkOverton . . . I added a simpler version.

Comment: Hi, @GordonLinoff, is there a reason `select 1` is used? Would say `select id`  work too? P.s I'm new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following:

```
select *
  from attempts a
 where
 (select count(t.id)
    from attempts_tag t
   where t.attemptid = a.id
     and t.tagid in (2, 11)) = 0

union all

select *
  from attempts a
 where not exists
 (select 1
    from attempts_tag t
   where t.attemptid = a.id);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this has worked - in the example provided this is returning ID's 42 and 43, where it should return 42, 43 and 44

Comment: I have modified the answer, I hope it will work.