# How to select rows where multiple values do not exist

Tags: sql, exists, not-exists

Scenario: Charlie, Amy and Robert have each filled out a survey which asks the user to select all the sports they are interested in. The question is multiple choice. In the table `surveyData` each row represents one of the answers each user chose. so Charlie(`0001`) chose `basketball`, `rugby`, `acrobatics` and `darts`.

I would like to select from the table all `surveyDataIds (users)` who did not choose exactly `basketball (0002)` and `rugby (0003)`. I believe what I'm trying to do here is perform a NAND type operation.

Desired result: When querying this table I would expect to return the following `surveyDataIds`: `0002` and `0004`. `surveyDataIds` would need to be grouped as to not have duplicates. Robert is not returned as he selected `basketball (0002)`.

Here is what I have tried so far, taking advice from the answer in this post [SELECT WHERE multiple records don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621474/select-where-multiple-records-dont-exist). Unfortunately, it does not work and is returning the wrong results.

```
select *
FROM surveyData sd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM surveyData sd2
    WHERE sd.surveyDataId = sd2.surveyDataId AND sd.chosenInterests in (2, 3)
)
```

`0001 = Charlie`
`0002 = Amy`
`0003 = Robert`
`0004 = Lauren`

```
interest options
0 = tennis
1 = football  
2 = basketball
3 = rugby  
4 = snooker  
5 = acrobatics 
6 = bowling 
7 = squash  
8 = cricket 
9 = darts   
10 = javelin
```

Table name: `surveyData`

| surveyDataId | chosenInterests |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2 |
| 0001 | 3 |
| 0001 | 5 |
| 0001 | 9 |
| 0002 | 6 |
| 0002 | 7 |
| 0002 | 9 |
| 0002 | 1 |
| 0002 | 4 |
| 0002 | 8 |
| 0003 | 2 |
| 0003 | 7 |
| 0004 | 10 |

Comment: I almost all cases, NOT EXISTS wants a correlated subquery.

Comment: I should state that I am an SQL novice. Could you please expand on a correlated subquery? EDIT: Ok I have added `sd.surveyDataId = sd2.surveyDataId AND` to the query, I think this makes it correlated? However the query still does not work as expected.

Comment: Your expected results don't match your description. None of your IDs have chosen *exactly* 2 and 3 so all of your IDs have not chosen 2 and 3; do you mean *at least* ?

Comment: Hi Stu, no not at least. I mean I want people who did not choose both 2 and 3. If they selected one of them I do not want them either. So that's why Robert isn't included as he chose 2. So it has to be both id are not selected. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing distinct, no? Otherwise please explain what does it mean 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Sorry, what I found was that my query was still picking up `chosenInterests` outside what was in the `in (2, 3)`.

Comment: @danielblythe, yes, I too missed you typed sd. alias in there. BTW with EXISTS queries, you don't need to invent something like "select 1", "select *" is just fine. It is a boolean check, not something to return column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NOT IN:

```
select distinct surveyDataId
FROM surveyData
WHERE surveyDataId NOT IN (
    SELECT surveyDataId
    FROM surveyData
    WHERE chosenInterests in (2,3)
);
```

BTW your query with EXISTS would work too:

```
select distinct surveyDataId
FROM surveyData sd1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM surveyData sd2
    WHERE sd1.surveyDataId = sd2.surveyDataId and chosenInterests in (2,3)
);
```

Comment: NOT IN is working for me. I will try and again with EXISTS but I could not get it to work. Thank you @Cetin Basoz.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just had the wrong alias used:

```
select distinct surveydataid
from surveydata sd
where not exists (
    select *
    from surveydata sd2
    where sd2.surveydataid=sd.surveydataid 
      and sd2.choseninterests in (2,3)
)
```

Comment: He was only missing "distinct surveyDataId" I think, but didn't say what it means "doesn't work and returning the wrong results".

Comment: No the example query refers to the outer table not the correlated table like it should do.

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't see he had sd. there. Without an alias it would work just fine.

Comment: thank you for your help Stu, I managed to get NOT IN to work in the end.

Comment: You should use the *not exists* approach, it's almost always the better method and can sometimes perform better, depending on your RDBMS, bot no worse.

Comment: @CetinBasoz *not* using an alias, although works by default in this context, is often a cause of confusion and the source of a number of Stack Overflow questions itself; aliases should always be used, regardless.

Comment: @Stu, you may use it, no harm. It is not a confusion to who knows SQL.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I wouldn't agree - anyone can easily overlook a missing alias - like you did on this very simple query here! I would maintain it's always good practice to alias everything :)

Comment: @Stu, of course we could agree to disagree. Aliasing is not a must everywhere and those who know SQL know it. Here it worked against to OP writing a wrong alias while trying to write an alias, if he left that out, it would be working.